# Defining in predicate logic, that 2 sets have equal cardinality through use of bijection

Tags: set-theory, predicate-logic

I'm trying to write formally in logic that 2 distinct sets A and B are bijective to each other and so have an equal cardinal number. This is my attempt, i think my definiton of an injective function seems a bit odd as its just the reverse of my surjective one. 
Many thanks in advance if you can help i really appreciate it.

$$(\forall y \in B, ~ \exists x \in A,  ~f(x)=y)\land(\forall x\in A, \exists y \in B, f(x)=y)$$

My method was first half defines surjective and the second half an injective function combining them gives bijection. My books on predicate logic dont use comma's is this allowed?

Comment: Just about your last point: sets aren't surjective, maps/functions are. If you have a surjection from $A$ to $B$, you can say that $A$ is at least as large as $B$. To make statements about the size of each set, you must determine an appropriate map between them or have a sufficient cardinality operator (such as $|A| = n$).

Answer (score 0):

I think your second one of the two statements connected by "and" should rather be:
$$\nexists x_1, x_2 \in A: (x_1 \neq x_2 \land f (x_1)=f (x_2))$$